Flutter keyboard language change issue
when I focus on the input, my keyboard opens, there is no problem here, but when I click on space on the keyboard, that is, when I long press, the modal for changing the language opens. There is a bug here, it opens, it closes immediately, and this error is written in the debigconsole.
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(10464): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
What might cause this bug? And how can I handle it?
